# how to get the slope of multiple columns in Python data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below data frame that carries 4 columns of scores. how do I find the slope of these 4 scores for each individual ID in my data  frame?

```
ID  t1  t2  t3  t4
a   1   2   3   4
b   3   2   1   
c   4   2   1   2
d   2   3   4   5
e   0   2   3   4
```

I would like the slope be appended back the same data frame and show the following after the slope is calculated.

```
ID  Slope
a   1
b   -1
c   -0.7
d   1
e   1.3
```

Comment: Do you want linear regression (the slope of the best fit) or do you want the average of each pair of slopes? Or something else? Your question isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sklearn` (or probably `scipy`) for this.  Example:

```
import sklearn

model = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
def get_coeff(row, model=model):
    # fit a row assuming points are separated by unit length and return the slope.
    
    row = row.copy().dropna()
    model.fit(np.arange(len(row)).reshape(-1,1), row.values.reshape(-1,1))
    slope = model.coef_[0][0]
    return slope


df["slope"] = df.apply(get_coeff, axis=1)
```

output:

```
    t1  t2  t3   t4  slope
ID
a    1   2   3  4.0    1.0
b    3   2   1  NaN   -1.0
c    4   2   1  2.0   -0.7
d    2   3   4  5.0    1.0
e    0   2   3  4.0    1.3
```